# Changing scene and game view orientation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried putting this in a script and attaching to the camera:
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

And I have also tried going to Project Settings > Player and setting it to portrait, as well as setting the build to ios, but both views are still the default landscape. Any idea how to change this

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make the unity editor in portrait mode:
Navigate to `Game Tab` there should be a tab where the Aspect ratio is being displayed.
Click on the drop-down, then click on the **`+`** icon and set the resolution to `9:16`, which will set the unity editor in portrait mode.
[image: change aspect ratio]

if you want to change the game application to portrait mode:
Navigate as following:

*`Edit -> Project Settings -> Player`*,

then in the inspector, you will find

" *`Resolution and Presentation`*".

There you can set default orientation for your application as per requirement.

Select Build Settings

[image: build settings]

Select Player setting in the bottom left
[image: player settings]

Select Resolution and Presentation
[image: change orientation]

The Answer is based on the following Unity version:

***Unity Hub --> 2.4.5***

***Unity --> 20201.6f1***

Answer (score 1):

Edit -> Project Settings -> Player, then in inspector you will find "Resolution and Presentation". There you can set default orientation for your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the portrait view in the Unity Editor, then you'll manage it in the Game Tab on the left hand side where it says "Free Aspect". Click on it and you will see a selection of resolution choices and click one that has a "Tall" in the name.

Answer (score 0):

so i was just wanting a quick easy way to view how my project might look based on orientation in the Unity editor before i built my project.

i came up with this method hack to still be able to get the desired results in the editor...

```
     public ScreenOrientation myScreenOrientation {
         get{
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
                if(Screen.height > Screen.width){
                    return ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
                } else {
                    return ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
                }
            #else
                return Screen.orientation;
            #endif
         }
     }
```

then instead of using `Screen.orientation` i use `myScreenOrientation`

I did not do this for `Input.deviceOrientation` because this may not be the same as what the screen orientation is... for example they could be laying in a bed with the phone overhead and it would read  as facedown which is nether landscape or portrait and did not help me with my ui layouts